# asp.net core mvc, finding correct _layout location when using custom location format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

inside the Controllers folder i have created a "Profile" subfolder (/Controllers/Profile), and i have used the code below add /Views/Profile/{controller}/{action} to View Location Formats.

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Profile/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

now i want to use the same layout for all Profile pages, and i want it to be /Views/Profile/_layout.cshtml, but it's not being recognized unless i put it inside the specific controller folder.

Is there any way to make each view look for _layout at its parent directory before checking /Views/Shared?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Insert(0, "/Views/Profile/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Insert(0, "/Views/Profile/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

there're two things that makes this work.
I've added "/Views/Profile/{0}" too and also used `.Insert(index, item)` instead of `.Add(item)`, this way these locations will be checked before the default ones.

but this is not a general solution to the problem, this only works for the folders i insert. I believe there's a better way using IViewLocationExpander and using namespace, something like [OdeToCode.AddFeatureFolders](https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders).

if anyone knows how to work with IViewLocationExpander (or understands [OdeToCode.AddFeatureFolders](https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders) source code) it would be really great if they could make a general solution.